# Python subprocess: Open a program and wait for user to save and close it

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I have a code which launches an excel file on GUI. It then get updated by user and closed. This user input is later used by program. So i want my program to wait until the user closes the excel file in GUI.
I tried following but it only waits for the program to open i guess.

```
import subprocess
loc = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Sheet_groups.xlsx"
p = subprocess.Popen(['start',loc],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell = True)
p.communicate()
```

PS: I am new to coding world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use psutil (process and system utilities) to check if Excel process is still open. Try this :

```
import psutil
import subprocess
import time
isopen=True

loc = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Sheet_groups.xlsx"
p = subprocess.Popen(['start',loc],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell = True)
time.sleep(2)
while(isopen):
    isopen="EXCEL.EXE" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()) 
    time.sleep(2)

print("File closed")
```

To Check if the specific windows is open you can use pywinauto library install it using.

`pip install pywinauto`

Then try :

```
import subprocess
import time
from pywinauto import Desktop

isopen=True
loc = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Sheet_groups.xlsx"
p = subprocess.Popen(['start',loc],shell = True)
time.sleep(2)

windows = Desktop(backend="uia").windows()

while(isopen):
    isopen="Sheet_groups.xlsx - Excel" in [w.window_text() for w in windows]
    time.sleep(2)
    
print("File closed")
```

You can try this if you can't use pywinauto:

```
import subprocess
import time
import win32gui

isopen=True
loc = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Sheet_groups.xlsx"
running=""

def winEnumHandler( hwnd, ctx ):
    global running
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible( hwnd ):
        running+=win32gui.GetWindowText( hwnd )
    
    

p = subprocess.Popen(['start',loc],shell = True)
time.sleep(2)

while(isopen):
    isopen=win32gui.EnumWindows( winEnumHandler, None )
    isopen="Sheet_groups.xlsx" in running
    running=""
    time.sleep(2)
    
print("File closed")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting `psutil.AccessDenied: psutil.AccessDenied (pid=8)` probably because i am in work laptop with no admin privilege's. Anyway dont you think your solution will take a toll on CPU resources if the user decides to keep excel open for longtime?@Fadi

Comment: Yes you need admin privilege's. It looks like it will use a lot of CPU resources if there is now delay in the loop which checks if Excel is still open. So I have fixed it by adding 2 seconds delay.

Comment: What if user has multiple excel files open? In that case the loop will remain open i guess. Is there any clean way of waiting like using threading and queuing?

Comment: Yes the loop will remain. You will need another approach to deal with this.

Comment: I have added a way to check for if specific windows is open but you need to install an external library.

Comment: This solution works fine. But unfortunately i need to run this in IronPython also and IronPython doesnot have pywinauto. Thanks @Fadi for the help.

Comment: I have added another solution that doesn't require an external library