# os.startfile() ı use but the program closes immediately why?

Tags: python

i get the file location from the text document but the program opens and closes immediately it won't open at all how can i fix this.
Is it because the problem is launcher.exe?
Example

```
file = open("fihrist.txt", "r")

read = file.readline()

os.startfile(read)
```

the code is an example, it was written in the same logic

Text file example
Text file [C:\Sobee\Game\launcher.exe]

Comment: It seems the program you are running is the issue if it is opening and closing itself immediately. What program are you running? Maybe try running a different program.

Comment: _but the program opens and closes immediately_ Do you mean **your python script** closes immediately, or **the program started by startfile()** closes immediately?

Comment: So... the first line of the file you opened contains the name of a file you want to open. Why not just use `os.startfile('c:/program files/game.exe')` as your [MRE]?

Comment: not functional in my code I'm running a single program but I was able to run another program with this method

Comment: So one program works, but another doesn't? Does it work when you open it directly from a string, rather than reading names from a file?

Comment: it works when i call this code in a different program but it doesn't run x program,I have not tried directly

Comment: What about John Gordan's comment? Is the problem that *your script* closes immediately, or *the program you run with `startfile`* closes immediately? Or both?

Comment: I'm talking about starting with startlife and ending right away yes that's exactly the error

Comment: Well... does that .exe behave the same way when you double-click on it?

Answer (score 1):

The method `os.startfile()` only starts an application it doesn't wait for the program to close.

If you want to run code after the program has ended you could try something like this: [Python subprocess: Open a program and wait for user to save and close it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64364965/python-subprocess-open-a-program-and-wait-for-user-to-save-and-close-it)

Comment: problem solved       os.chdir(r'C:\Sobee\game')    
        os.startfile('launcher.exe')